# Using AJAX or jQuery in WordPress to Return Results of PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an HTML form that accepts user input:

```
<form action="script_conv.php" method="post">
Convert: <input type="number" name="input" id="input">
<select name="unit1" id="unit1">
<option value="w">Words</option>
<option value="l">Lines</option>
<option value="p">Pages</option>
<option value="r">Recorded Minutes</option>
<option value="f">Finished Minutes</option>
</select>
to
<select name="unit2" id="unit2">
<option value="w">Words</option>
<option value="l">Lines</option>
<option value="p">Pages</option>
<option value="r">Recorded Minutes</option>
<option value="f">Finished Minutes</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The php script takes the user data and performs some calculations:

```
<?php
$input=$_POST["input"];
$unit1=$_POST["unit1"];
$unit2=$_POST["unit2"];

(bunch of if...else statements)

echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>$cat1f</li>";
echo "<li>$cat2f</li>";
echo "<li>$cat3f</li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

This all works fine, but of course the results of the function are returned to a new page. I'd like to append the results of the function to the same page. I know this will require AJAX/jQuery, but nothing I've tried has worked. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try test.php(html):-

```
<form method='post'>
Convert: <input type="number" name="input" id="input">
<select name="unit1" id="unit1">
<option value="w">Words</option>
<option value="l">Lines</option>
<option value="p">Pages</option>
<option value="r">Recorded Minutes</option>
<option value="f">Finished Minutes</option>
</select>
to
<select name="unit2" id="unit2">
<option value="w">Words</option>
<option value="l">Lines</option>
<option value="p">Pages</option>
<option value="r">Recorded Minutes</option>
<option value="f">Finished Minutes</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="getvalue();">
</form>
```

test.php (script function):-

```
<script src="http://localhost:8004/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function getvalue() {
       var input= document.getElementById('input').value;
    var unit1=document.getElementById('unit1').value;
    var unit2=document.getElementById('unit2').value;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8004/test/test.php",
        data: { input: input,unit1:unit1, unit2:unit2,fun:'getvalue' }
        }).done(function( data ) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }); 
}

</script>
```

php code at the top of this (test.php)file:-

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['fun']) == 'getvalue') 
{
echo $_REQUEST['input'].$_REQUEST['unit1'].$_REQUEST['unit2'];
exit();
}
?>
```

You need to exit else it will display all the data from this file so use another way using php for doing in php

remove action from `<form method="post">` and get response on the same page

Comment: This worked great. I had most of this but I was missing a piece of information, which you supplied. Thanks again - I've been banging my head against this for a couple of days!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('/path/to/your/php', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something with the response
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will helpfull for you and fulfill your requirement
http://sharp-coders.blogspot.in/2012/06/submit-form-using-ajax-without.html